# document.getElementById("componentID").clientHeight always give a zero in componentDidMount() function

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to get the height of the header after the page loads exactly.

I am trying to save the height in the state in the componentDidMount() by calling

```
document.getElementById("Header").clientHeight
```

but it always return 0 in componentDidMount().
Also i tried to call

```
document.getElementById("Header").getClientRects()[0].height
```

but also it failed beacause .getClientRects() returns empty array.
The two methods works in any other function than componentDidMount()

Comment: here is the code https://ideone.com/ZoWCTI

Comment: does it work with window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Header")).height ? (you might have to remove the "px")

Comment: window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Header")) returns auto

Comment: what "px" do you mean ? from where do i have to remove it ?

Comment: well in all the examples ive tried it returns something like "123px" as height (did you add .height after the call oO still for it to return auto sounds weird)

Comment: yes of-course console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Header")).height) it prints "auto"

Comment: could it jsut be that componentDidMOunt is too early to get the height ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl that's exactly was the problem so when i used timeout and let it wait 100 ms it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try wrapping it in timeout?

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
     document.getElementById("Header").clientHeight
   },0)
}
```

Comment: the zero makes it wait 0 ms so if i changed it to any other like 100 ms it works perfectly ! thanks a lot !